# Can't edit number input react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a number input that I'd like to bind to a state:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            num: 100,
        };
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ num: event.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <input
                        autofocus="true"
                        type="number"
                        value={this.state.num}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
```

So if I edit the input, the state should change. But I can't even edit the input. Why?

Comment: beacuse your input does not have `onChange` handler

Answer (score 2):

You currently see the number 100 displayed in the input, that corresponds to the initial state of your component.

What you need to do now, is to change the state when something is typed into the input, so the component will re-render.

Example:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      num: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

And then pass it to your `<input>` like `<input onChange={this.handleChange} ..... />`

See the following working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zn0j79l8kx?fontsize=14